# Inequalty of products

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I am trying to prove something regarding roots of a function, can we say that the following correct for any $x_{i}$? above any field?

$$|x_{1}\times x_{2}\times...\times x_{n}|\leq |x_{1}|\times |x_{2}|\times... \times |x_{n}|$$

Comment: Well, any field with an absolute product. In the usual real and rational and complex fields (and between), we have an exact equality there.

Comment: @DonAntonio why can we say that it is equality?

Comment: You can factor out $\pm 1$ to make it a product of positive numbers.

Comment: @gbox Use what Matt wrote.

Comment: For complex numbers you'd factor out a complex number with modulus $1$ to make it a product of positive reals. I don't know about other fields with absolute value.